# Can I log into Windows OpenSSH with default shell as pwsh.exe?

Tags: bash, ssh, virtualbox, powershell

I can't login to Windows OpenSSH is my default shell is **not** powershell. If it is, then

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH /v DefaultShell /d C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

makes the login work.

However, gitlab uses bash, which isn't available on power shell, so it uses pwsh.exe. However, if I set

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "$PSHOME\pwsh.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

as suggested here https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/virtualbox.html, then SSH login won't work. If I leave powershell.exe, then it works but then it can't use bash

Comment: Can you give us more then "it does not work", what happens exactly, more importantly what does the server thing is happening?  Why are you not just calling `ssh ..` since the OpenSSH client is installed by default on Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound I installed the openssh client natively, and did `ssh MACHINENAME\Username@localhost` and typed my password, but it gives `Permission denied, please try again`. If the default shell is `powershell.exe`, it works. If it is `pwsh.exe` then it does not work giving permission denied problem

Comment: You installed the client.  Did you install the OpenSSH Server daemon?   pwsh.exe is the PowerShell core executable. You absolutely should be able to use "Windows Subystem for Linux" bash if you use PowerShell 5.1

Comment: @Ramhound I installed both the client and server. And I believe I can't use WSL because I'm already inside a VM. This is a VM for gitlab to run CI/CD on. I'm following https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/virtualbox.html#checklist-for-windows-vms where it needs pwsh.exe

Comment: When the default shell is powershell.exe the server works, gitlab logs into it but tries to use bash and fails